# What prevents miners from removing transactions when validating a node?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, mining-theory, block-validity

Simple question: when a miners receives a block of transactions, he can't add fraudulent transactions because they need to be appropriately signed, but what prevents him from erasing a tx? If he manage to find the correct nonce of the modified block, as I understand it will still be a valid block accepted by the blockchain.

Comment: I think that's a different question. That's can a miner ignore a transaction when mining a block versus can a miner receive a mined block and take a transaction out of it. Related though I guess.

Comment: Yes it was not exactly the same but still answered my question. In fact it doesn't matter, the erased Tx will still be available for others minors to pick it up and it will eventually be processed if corresponding fees are competitive. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If a miner makes any change to a block the proof of work is no longer valid and it has to start the mining process from scratch again. So a miner can refuse to accept a valid block mined by another miner but it generally isn't in their interests to as the rest of the miners will have moved onto attempting to mine the next block on top of that block.